# Python `requests` to get a generator object for JSON response

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, python-requests

I am using Python's `requests` library to get a huge JSON response.

Normally, when I do `data = resp.json()` it takes around 5 seconds.

Then I tried `ujson` as `data = ujson.loads(resp.text)`, which took around 2 seconds.

Is there a way in which I can get a `generator`-like object from response? I know we have the `streaming` facility available, but I guess that will give me data in chunks, whereas I need data as **per element** as I may then iterate it over  `for` loop.

And while all this is to reduce the time further, is the above method even possible? Or is there any other way in which this can be achieved (I am open to any other library as well)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The [`json-stream`](https://pypi.org/project/json-stream/#requests) module has direct support for streaming a JSON document from a `requests` response, with which you can simply iterate over items of the nested dicts and/or lists as they are generated from the stream.

The example below streams a ~211MB JSON document of the world's COVID-19 statistics:

```
import requests
import json_stream.requests

json_url = 'https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/owid-covid-data.json'

with requests.get(json_url, stream=True) as response:
    data = json_stream.requests.load(response)
    for name, record in data.items():
        print('Region:', name)
        for key, value in record.items():
            if key == 'data':
                for entry in value:
                    for k, v in entry.items():
                        print(k, v)
            else:
                print(key, value)
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing1/DeliriousLustrousSubweb